# What is the word term paper called in Britain?

Tags: word-request, british-english

I checked *term paper* on OED and it shows that it is AmE.
So what is the British one for it?

Answer (score 4):

The UK education system doesn't usually require a long assessed essay at the end of each term. If a particular teacher does decide to set such an essay it would be called an *end of term essay*.  (or *end of year*, if due in June/July).  In general assessment by essay or similar during the course (in contrast to examinations) is called "coursework"

> I can't believe that my History teacher set an end of term essay. It has to be 5 pages long!
>
> I've to do my Art coursework this week, so I won't have time to do any other homework.